# Ruby on Rails. Как создать и сохранить docx

Tags: windows, ruby

Есть Ruby-строка с содержимым файла формата docx (документ MS Office Word).
Нужно сохранить её в файл. Под Windows.

Самый простой способ не работает:

```
File.write(filename, contents)
```

Полученный файл не открывется. Почему? Как это решить?

Comment: Вопрос не сводится к простой записи бинарного содержимого в файл?

Comment: Я хтмл конвертирую в markdown потом markdown в docx и эти данные нужно записать в файл. Они имеют другой вид чем обычный текст, даные с форматированием, но может я чтото не так делаю. В этом случае даные не записываются простым способом типа
 open('testfile.docx', 'w') { |f| f.puts @converter.convert }

Comment: Решил задачу так:
file = File.new("my_xml_data_file.docx", "wb")
file.write(data)
file.close

Answer (score 0):

В Windows есть особенность: файлы по умолчанию открываются в **текстовом** режиме, преобразующим между `\r\n` (в файле) и `\n` (в Руби) (при выводе, как здесь; при вводе же есть ещё эффекты вокруг Ctrl+Z/EOF, [см. опцию `t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)).

Поэтому при записи бинарных данных в файл необходимо явно указывать `b` в режиме открытия файла, например так ([c `IO.write`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-write); NB: `File` наследует `IO`):

```
File.write(filename, contents, mode: "wb")
```

...иначе голый байт `0A` будет выведен как два байта: `0D 0A`, и в файле окажется не совсем то, что было в исходной строке и это наверняка не прочитается требуемым ПО.

<sub>Написано по мотивам [комментария автора вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848053/ruby-on-rails-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-docx#comment1363729_848053).</sub>